# How to validate and create on laravel 5.2 on controller?

Tags: php, controller, insert, laravel-5

Hello I'm trying to create a code generator to invite a user from input email, I want to save on the database the user id who send the invite, the code, and the email who is going to recive the invite, but I can't get the id of my auth user doing $request->user('id') (not working) also I know there is other method to do this easier than using DB::table something like 
$request->user()->invites()->create... my controller looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class invitacionController extends Controller
{


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

    }


    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('administrar');
    }



    public function invitacion(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:invites',
        ]);

        /*$request->user()->invites()->create([
            'code' => str_random(40),
        ]);*/
        DB::table('invites')->insert([
        ['usuId' => $request->user('id'), 'code' => str_random(40), 'email' =>  $request->input('email')],
        ]);

        return redirect('/administrar');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship is properly configured, the first (commented) method should be working.

As for the second method, I think you are adding extra brackets:

```
DB::table('invites')->insert([
    'usuId' => $request->user()->id, // <--- 
    'code' => str_random(40),
    'email' =>  $request->input('email')
]);
```

---

That `hasMany` method can take additional parameters. By default it expects the column to be named `user_id`, but you called it `usuId`. The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) gives this example:

`return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key');`

So I think you should do

```
public function invites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Invite::class, 'usuId');
}
```

Comment: using $request->user()->id works fine but the correct method it's the commented one i think, with relationship you mean foreign keys or just eloquend? because there i have it like that

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

User.php

public function invites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Invite::class);
}

Comment: thanks works like a charm, one question more, it adds everything excepts the email, to get it i have to write this: $request->user()->invites()->create([
   'code' => str_random(40),
   'email' =>  $request->input('email'),

        ]);

it's normal?

Comment: Yes, the `create` only adds automatically the user_id. Any other fields you should specify manually.

Comment: once more time thanks for all your time, appreciate it, all solved

Comment: Great, glad I could help ;)